# How to marshal map to xml without tag value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a HashMap which I want to convert to XML:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OrdersAdapter.class)
private Map<Long, Order> orders = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Order>();
```

By default map is converted to `<entry><key></key><value></value><entry>`, but I wanted to get XML, where key is attribute and there is no value tag. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<productsMap>
    <orders>
        <order orderId="1">
           <prodId>123</prodId>
           <price>1</price>
        </order>
        <order orderId="2">
           <prodId>15</prodId>
           <price>10</price>
        </order>
    </orders>
</productsMap>
```

Using my program from github: https://github.com/pfryn/simpleTestProject/tree/master/src/pl/shop , now I am able to generate xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<productsMap>
    <orders>
        <order orderId="1">
            <value>
                <prodId>123</prodId>
                <price>1</price>
            </value>
        </order>
        <order orderId="2">
            <value>
                <prodId>15</prodId>
                <price>10</price>
            </value>
        </order>
    </orders>
</productsMap>
```

Do you know how to avoid "value" tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OrderType**

```
public class OrderType {

    public List<Order> order =
            new ArrayList<Order>();
}
```

**OrdersAdapter**

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends XmlAdapter<OrderType, Map<Long, Order>> {

    @Override
    public Map<Long, Order> unmarshal(OrderType v) throws Exception {
        Map<Long, Order> hashMap = new HashMap<Long, Order>();
        for (Order myEntryType : v.order) {
            hashMap.put(myEntryType.orderId, myEntryType);
        }
        return hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderType marshal(Map<Long, Order> map) throws Exception {
        OrderType ordType = new OrderType();
        for (Entry<Long, Order> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Order ordEntryType =
                    new Order();
            ordEntryType.orderId = entry.getKey();
            ordEntryType.price = entry.getValue().price;
            ordEntryType.prodId = entry.getValue().prodId;
            ordType.order.add(ordEntryType);
        }
        return ordType;
    }

}
```

**Order**

```
public class Order {

    public Order(){
        super();
    }
    public Order(Long prodId, BigDecimal price) {
        this();
        this.prodId = prodId;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Long orderId;

    public Long prodId;
    public BigDecimal price;

}
```

**OUTPUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<productsMap>
    <orders>
        <order orderId="1">
            <prodId>123</prodId>
            <price>1</price>
        </order>
        <order orderId="2">
            <prodId>15</prodId>
            <price>10</price>
        </order>
    </orders>
</productsMap>
```